# Adding a content dynamically issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a block content by appending it to a div on a button click. The issue is that, it is adding the content below the button `Add Section`. It should add the content above the `Add Section` button, i.e where it is commented. My code is as follows:

Can someone please help ? I want the content to be added above `div class="g"` each time I click the `Add Section` button.

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
            <input type="text" id="user-title-1" class="d" value="user 1">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button edit-title-btn">
            </button>
        </div>

                <div class="e">
                    <ul>  
                            for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="user-@j-1">
                                    <label for="user-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>

                <div class="f">
                    <small class="_availability">
                        <span class="title"> Section 1 </span>
                    </small>

                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button btn-show js-show-supplier">
                        <span class="show">Show <i class="icon-show"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- New section to be added here
            //
        -->

            <div class="g">
                <button type="button" class="mdl-button add-Section-btn js-add-Section">
                    AddSection
                </button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="mdl-button secondary-btn js-save">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>  


<script>

    $(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-Section', function () {
                var content = `<div class="e">
                    <ul>  
                            for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="user-@j-1">
                                    <label for="user-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <div class="f">
                    <small class="_availability">
                        <span class="title"> Section 1 </span>
                    </small>

                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button btn-show js-show-supplier">
                        <span class="show">Show <i class="icon-show"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>`

            $(this).closest('.b').append(content);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change `append()` function to `insertBefore()`

**Here is an working example**

```js
$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-Section', function() {
  var content = `<div class="e">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="user-@j-1">
                        <label for="user-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="f">
                    <small class="_availability">
                        <span class="title"> Section 1 </span>
                    </small>

                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button btn-show js-show-supplier">
                        <span class="show">Show <i class="icon-show"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>`;

  $(content).insertBefore($(this).closest('.g'));
});

$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-show-supplier', function() {
  alert('Clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <input type="text" id="user-title-1" class="d" value="user 1">
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button edit-title-btn">
            </button>
    </div>

    <div class="e">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="user-@j-1">
          <label for="user-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="f">
        <small class="_availability">
          <span class="title"> Section 1 </span>
        </small>

        <button type="button" class="mdl-button btn-show js-show-supplier">
          <span class="show">Show <i class="icon-show"></i></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="g">
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button add-Section-btn js-add-Section">
         AddSection
      </button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button secondary-btn js-save">
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Do you mean something like this?

```js
$(".main").on('change', '.js-cars-itemas [type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index(); //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked"); //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this; //Checkbox object

  $(this).closest('.cars').find('.js-cars-itemas').each(function() { //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
  });

  var checkeds = [];
  $(this).closest(".cars").find(".cars-itemas input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})

$('.js-add-category').click(function() {

  var categoryContent = `<div class="cars">

<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
<button type="button" class="js-save-section">Save</button>
</div> <br>`

  $('.main').append(categoryContent);

});


$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-section', function() {
  var sectionContent = `<div class="cars-item js-cars-itemas">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6>
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6>
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6>
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul> </div>`


 
  $(this).closest('.cars').append(sectionContent);

});

$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-save-section', function() {
 var parent = $(this).closest(".cars").addClass("saved");
  setTimeout(function() {
    parent.removeClass("saved");
  }, 2E3);
});
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.cars {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  transition: border-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.cars.saved {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="js-add-category">Add Category</button> <br> <br>

<div class="main">

  <div class="cars">

    <div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
          <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
          <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
          <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
    <button type="button" class="js-save-section">Save</button>
    <br>

    <div class="section">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
```

Comment: For each generated `Show` button. how can I invoked separate function upon each section ?  I am using `        $(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-show', function () {
            alert('Clicked');
        });` but its showing alert the number of times that I click on `Show`

Comment: @jones Is alert showing more than once after click? Because I tested it and it showed me only once. Check my edited snippet

Comment: @jones hmm, it appears that you have minor errors in this fiddle, but still after repairing them alert shows only once per click. It is difficult for me to find the reason if I can not see the problem :) What exactly is not working and how would you like it to work?

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, when if you click on `Add Category` another blue box appears with an initial row of checkboxes. Inside this blue box, you can add another rows of checkboxes. What I want to achieve is to when I click `Save` in each blue box, it should alert only the concerned blue box in which the button `Save` was clicked.

Comment: @jones Take a look at edit and tell me if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Hmm.. this is the behaviour I want. But for each box, I want an event to occur. Say, alert for example. 

I have tried `  $(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-save-section', function () {
            var parent = $(this).closest('.cars').alert('Hi');
        });`

In the future, I will have this `var pareint = $(this).closest('.cars').StepA();`

Comment: @jones ok great. If you used my solution then please click green check sign. As to `alert()` it is not a function that you can bind to an element. Alert is a way to display a message in a browser. But you can do whatever you want inside this `click()` event. So I guess that your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

There is prepend() for your case. Like I explain by the simplest example.

Suppose there is a list like:

```
<ul id="counting">
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

I want to append "one" on top of list not at the end. This can be achieved by the function:

```
$("#counting").prepend("<li>one</li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change `$(this).closest('.b').append(content);`  to `$('.g').before(content);` Here is working code.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-Section', function () {
                var content = `<div class="e">
                    <ul>  
                            for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="user-@j-1">
                                    <label for="user-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <div class="f">
                    <small class="_availability">
                        <span class="title"> Section 1 </span>
                    </small>

                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button btn-show js-show-supplier">
                        <span class="show">Show <i class="icon-show"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>`

            $('.g').before(content);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
            <input type="text" id="user-title-1" class="d" value="user 1">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button edit-title-btn">
            </button>
        </div>

                <div class="e">
                    <ul>  
                            for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="user-@j-1">
                                    <label for="user-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>

                <div class="f">
                    <small class="_availability">
                        <span class="title"> Section 1 </span>
                    </small>

                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button btn-show js-show-supplier">
                        <span class="show">Show <i class="icon-show"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- New section to be added here
            //
        -->

            <div class="g">
                <button type="button" class="mdl-button add-Section-btn js-add-Section">
                    AddSection
                </button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="mdl-button secondary-btn js-save">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```